# Middleware to render an HTML navigation index for an express application

Tags: node.js, express

I am looking for some sort of node.js utility that automatically builds a navigation index based on the routes of an express application and renders it as an HTML view. This is useful on development phase to check all endpoints provided by an express instance and perform some requests for available paths.

I know an express instance stores all routes in `_router` property and I can parse this object and its `stack` to build an HTML view with links to the corresponding routes. Is this the right approach of building such an index?

**UPDATED on 2017-05-08 based on @Tolsee [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759034/middleware-to-render-an-html-navigation-index-for-an-express-application?noredirect=1#comment74562639_43759034)**:

Apparently, I am looking for the [sitemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map) feature, but in HTML format instead of XML (which is useful for crawlers but not so friendly for end-users). So, I found the npm package [express-sitemap-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sitemap-html), which is an express middleware that builds an HTML sitemap dynamically. For now I did not find any better alternative.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I am not asking to recommend or find. I already looked for it and did not find. I am just asking if it already exists, or not?

Comment: that's the same thing!

Comment: I think you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sitemap and render it in your page.